# Why does brass fracture at a 45° angle?

Tags: stress-strain, metals, solid-mechanics, fracture

These images were from a demonstration of a brass sample exposed to intense longitudinal (axial) pressure. Initially it was squashed resulting in some bulging outwards and sideways distortion, but ultimately it suddenly fractured.

**Image 1 - At just about the moment of fracture:**

[image]

**Image 2 - A very short time later:**
[image]

([Source video](https://youtu.be/JyA1lBJl_qM?t=382))

Although it was not actually stated in the video, the fracture angle looks to be about 45°. Also note that the fracture surfaces appear to be quite smooth and consistent.

What is the reason the sample broke at this specific angle? For instance, it could have instead fragmented into numerous small pieces with random shapes (as glass might do, for instance).

Comment: What structure does brass have that glass doesn’t?

Comment: That's because materials don't fail by compression. For an axial applied force the normal stress (stress is the generalization of force from acting on a point to acting over a surface, normal stress acts perpendicular to the surface) can be transformed to a shear stress (shear stress acts tangent to the surface) with a 45° rotation... Basically, if you look at a volume element rotated by 45° you'll see that in that reference frame it 'feels' a shear stress and not a compressive one. The test basically tells you that the brass test piece fractured due to shear stress.